# Use JSoup to get all textual links

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to grab content from web pages.

I want to get all the links on a page that have some contained text (it doesn't matter what the text is) just needs to be non-empty/image etc.

Example of links I want:

```
<a href="somepage.html">Link to Some Page</a>
```

Since it contains the text "Link to Some Page"

Links I don't want:

```
<a href="somepage.html"><img src="someimage.jpg"/></a>
<a href="somepage.html"></a>
```

My code looks like this. How can I modify it to only get the first type of link?

```
Document document = // I get my document object
Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a[href]") 
for (Element page : linksOnPage) {
    String link = page.attr("abs:href");
    // I do stuff with the link
}
```

Comment: My bad, this is actually quite simple: I should be able to use :matches(regex) ... just need to find the correct regex

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this.
It does it's job though it's probably not the fanciest solution out there.

Note: the function `text()` gets you a clean text so if there are any HTML code fragements inside it, it won't return them.

```
Document doc = // get the doc
Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a");

for (Element pageElem : linksOnPage){
    String link = "";
    if(pageElem.text().trim().equals(""))
       continue;
    // do smth with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and it's working fine:

```
Document document = // I get my document object
Elements linksOnPage = document.select("a:matches(([^\\s]+))"); 
for (Element page : linksOnPage) {
    String link = page.attr("abs:href");
    // I do stuff with the link
}
```